# Configuring IIS7.5 with Coldfusion 9.0.1

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-9

I am trying for the past couple of days to configure IIS 7.5 and coldfusion to run on my local machine but I hit a wall.

I have two sites that I am trying to create a run locally but 1 of them is working and the other one does not.

My coldfusion admin is working and I was able to set up my settings (db connections and stuff).

Under IIS management I am creating a site, assign it to the correct folder on my machine set the path as "local.site1.com" and everything runs as it should.

When I am trying to do the same thing for Site2, I'm getting a message from Chrome saying "Oops! Google Chrome could not find local.site2.com"

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you added `local.site2.com` to your hostfile?

Comment: i had to add all of my sites to the hosts file and now it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `local.site2.com` to your hostfile

Comment: File `host`, located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

Answer (score 0):

Are both sites pointing to the same codebase if so that is difficult to achieve with IIS7 and 7.5?

Comment: I forgot to edit my hosts file. I had to point the sites to an IP